# jQuery - Find UL of LI

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable, listitem

Hey guys I was just wondering whether there is a way to find out what Unordered List the List Item is in? So like for example I have a UL with the ID 1 and another one with the ID 2 and I'd have the List Items under both Unordered List sortable but on update I want to find out what Unordered List the List Item has been left in.

How Would I do this?

Comment: can you show an example of the HTML?  It's certainly possible but implementation depends on your markup.

Comment: Have you tried `$('li:selected').parents('ul')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use `closest` rather than `parents` in case you have nested lists.  `closest` will only return the nearest ancestor matching the selector as opposed to `parents` which will return all ancestors matching (potentially multiple instead of just one).

Assuming in your case `this` is your `li`:

```
$(this).closest("ul");
```

Comment: Thanks I'm guessing that this would be the best solution since I might end up using mutiple ul's

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `parents()` method for that

```
$("#ID1").parents("ul");
```

Answer (score 0):

just find `its parent ul using` `parent()`

```
$("li").parents("ul");
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/WR28X/)